# Some questions about Thinkpad Tablet

Tags: internet, 3g, lenovo-thinkpad-tablet

I need to purchase a tablet for on the move access to web, video, book reading etc. I am a Thinkpad fan so I would like to go for Lenovo Thinkpad. However I have some questions regarding it, which seems to be related more with Android itself than the hardware.

1. Thinkpad tablet has USB port, so can we use external USB modem (e.g. MTS MBlaze, Tata Photon in India) with it to connect to internet. On some forums it is said that Android does not have drivers of USB modem, so we can use USB modems with any Android tablet in the market even if they contain full USB port. What is the current state of Android on this?
2. A bit on hardware side, Thinkpad contains SIM slot and it is only yesterday when Lenovo has added Gobi chip for 3G capability. So, what was the use of that SIM card slot before that chip?

Answer (score 1):

1. AFAIK Android has **no support** for UMTS/LTE/mobile-connectivity USB-Sticks.
2. The SIM slot was always used for mobile connectivity. The [Gobi chip supports more technology for mobile connectivity](http://wraltechwire.com/business/tech_wire/news/blogpost/10417444/), allowing the Thinkpad to establish mobile connectivity in various countries. With a normal chip you are restricted to your region.

Comment: 1. Very said. :( Is there any plan in near future versions of Android for this support.
2. If there is mobile connectivity without Gobi chip, what is the use of introducing Gobi chip now with 130$ more than normal version.

Comment: @vikas I have updated my answer

Comment: I am still unable to understand the difference because if with normal chip we were able to access internet via mobile networks, even only in our region, it would have been great for many users. They can at least use the tablet to access internet on move in their region.